# Why is Python debug using correct virtual environment but RUN fails even though correct Python interpreter selected?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-10

I have a `.virtualenvs` folder with `venv` and `venv2`. I have installed the `requests` module in `venv2` but NOT in `venv1`, and not global. I have a file `app.py` with the following code:

```py
import requests
r = requests.get('https://github.com')
print(r.status_code)
print("Hello Virtual World")
```

In the VS Code settings, I have Python virtualenvs path: `~/.virtualenvs`.

When I open this code and have Python Interpreter as Global or `venv1`, "requests" is underlined (could not be resolved). When I switch to Python Interpreter for `venv2`, the underline disappears as expected.

The problem is, if I **run** the code (Ctrl-Alt-N), I get an error `no module named 'requests'`. But when I run in DEBUG mode, the code runs and returns code 200 and prints "Hello Virtual World". I did notice that DEBUG first invokes the `Activate.ps1` script. Why is this not run when I switch Python Interpreter?
Do I have to activate the venv I need each time despite selecting the correct Python interpreter?

I'm using Python 3.9 / VSCode / Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of `Code Runner`, You can refer to [here](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/434) for more details.

And you can run the python file with the command of `Run Python File in Terminal`, this can avoid this problem.